# EntityFramework: Não existe mapeamento do tipo de objeto ObjectParameter para um provedor gerenciado de tipo nativo

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework-6

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação MVC com Entity Framework em Code First.

Como minha base de dados possui procedures, optei por usar SQLQuery para executar as procedures, mas estou me deraparando com esse erro:

```
 Não existe mapeamento do tipo de objeto System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter para um provedor gerenciado de tipo nativo.
```

Segue código da classe DbContext:

```
public DTODados GetDadosProcedure(string codUsuario, string senhaCript)
{
    return Database.SqlQuery<DTODados>("ProcedureGenerica", 
        codUsuario != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("codUsuario", codUsuario) :
            new ObjectParameter("codUsuario", typeof(string)), 
        senhaCript != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("senhaCript", senhaCript) :
            new ObjectParameter("senhaCript", typeof(string))
    ).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Seguindo esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149919/no-mapping-exists-from-object-type-system-collections-generic-list-when-executin), tentei mudar para SqlParameter, mas ao executar, arremesso outra exceção informando que a procedure espera os parâmetros, mesmo eles presentes (tentei colocar o `new SqlParameter("@codUsuario", codUsuario)` e sem @, mas não funcionou).

Grato a quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido: alterei para SqlParameters e defini corretamente os parametros:

```
public DTODados GetDadosProcedure(string codUsuario, string senhaCript)
{
    return Database.SqlQuery<DTODados>("ProcedureGenerica @codUsuario , @senhaCript", 
        new SqlParameter("@codUsuario", codUsuario),
        new SqlParameter("@senhaCript", senhaCript) 
    ).SingleOrDefault();
}
```